# TestServer to use real sql database

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm creating integration tests for ASP.NET Core WebAPI. I'm trying to make TestServer to use real, NOT in memory, sql-server database.

The first problem was, that WebHostBuilder didn't see connection string in "connectionstring.json", so I moved connection string cofnig to "appsettings.json". Now WebHostBuilder loads the connection string from appsettings.json file, but it doesn't load any data from sql-server database when executing a query (returns empty collection). It does, when I run it normally (not as testserver) and do GET through Postman.

My question is: "Is it possible to make TestServer to use sql-server database and how to do it?"

I found a similar question here [call api Test server : .net core API integration tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46400824/call-api-test-server-net-core-api-integration-tests) , but there is no answer how to make TestSever works with sql-server database.

**TestServer:**

```
_server = new TestServer(WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder()
            .UseEnvironment("Development")
            .ConfigureAppConfiguration(AddConfigFiles)
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
           );
```

**AddConfigFiles** method:

```
        public static void AddConfigFiles(WebHostBuilderContext hostingContext, IConfigurationBuilder config)
    {
        var env = hostingContext.HostingEnvironment;
        config
            .AddJsonFile("connectionstrings.json", optional: true)
            .AddJsonFile($"connectionstrings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true)
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true);

        config.AddEnvironmentVariables();
    }
```

**Connection string**

```
"Data Source={MyServerName};Initial Catalog={MyDatabaseName};Integrated Security=True;"
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, if you want to see a full setup look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54858071/2482439

In the example, the database used is SQLite but you can change the DatabaseType configuration to use SQL Server or any other.

Remember that the configuration files must be in the folder of the test project that are currently executing the tests, the scope, the path is defined by that.
So if you have Project.Integration.Tests, in the root folder you need to have connectionstrings.Development.json and appsettings.Development.json.

Also, you should probably set required true, for those config you really need.